# Operator overloading modulus function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm supposed to do an overloading of the modulus function, but I'm not sure how to do it. Let me know if you require more information.

This is my requirement by my school:

Member function that rotates a Point about the origin by the specified number of degrees. Returns a new Point

Inside the driver file, my school wants the modulus function to accomplish this scenario:

Point pt1(-50, -50);
  double angle = 45;
  Point pt2 = pt1 % angle;

This is what I've tried:

```
Point Point::operator%( int value)
{
    (int)x%value;

    (int)y%value;

    return *this;
}

//point.h file

 class Point
 {
   public:
       // Constructors (2)
  explicit Point(double x, double y); 

  Point();

   double getX() const;

   double getY() const;

   Point operator+(const Point& other)const ;

   Point& operator+(double value);

   Point operator*(double value) ;

   Point operator%(int value);

   Point operator-(const Point& other)const ;

   Point operator-(double value);

   Point operator^(const Point& other);

   Point operator+=(double value);
   Point& operator+=(const Point& other) ;

   Point& operator++();
   Point operator++(int); 

   Point& operator--(); 
   Point operator--(int); 

   Point& operator-();

        // Overloaded operators (14 member functions)
   friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Point 
  &point );
    friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream  &input, Point 
  &point );

    // Overloaded operators (2 friend functions)

private:
  double x; // The x-coordinate of a Point
  double y; // The y-coordinate of a Point

    // Helper functions
  double DegreesToRadians(double degrees) const;
  double RadiansToDegrees(double radians) const;
};

 // Point& Add(const Point& other); // Overloaded operators (2 non-member, non-friend functions)
    // Point& Multiply(const Point& other);
    Point operator+( double value, const Point& other );
    Point operator-( double value, const Point& other );
```

Comment: Please tell us what went wrong

Comment: Just wanted to point out that taking x mod the angle and y mod the angle is meaningless if what you want to do is rotate the point by angle. (The other thing to wonder about is why they want the "%" to mean rotate, but oh well.) Here is a formula for rotating a point in cartesian coordinates given some angle: https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/

EDIT: Also, I assume the reason you just applied the % to each field is cuz that's what you have to do for the other operators (where their meaning is derived from the meaning of those symbols on each coordinate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error I see is that you didn't respect the requirements of your assignement. Your assignement specifically ask for your type to support this operation:

```
Point pt1{-50, 50};
Point pt2 = pt1 % 45.5;
```

This infer that your operator must return a point with the operation apply to it using a double. You clearly store the angle as double, but receive an int. That is not respecting your requirement. Also, you return a rotated point, but not the right one. You're making the operation in-place instead of making the operation on a new point. Inside your operator, you should create a point with the new position. Something like this:

```
Point Point::operator%(double) const {
    return Point{..., ...};
}
```

Then, your operation is wrong. You cast the point data member to `int`only to do a modulo on them. A modulo don't do a rotation. A rotation is usually done with a sine and a cosine. You cannot use the C++ `%`operator on int to make a rotation.

Comment: Oh right. ok. so any idea on how i should write the codes? cuz i dun.. Anyway, according to the requirements by my school i need to use the % operator...

Comment: Operator Functionality Description 
% Rotation 
Member function that rotates a Point about the origin by the specified number of degrees. Returns a new Point.

Comment: ^ is the requirement

Comment: @user10995546 You cannot use the operator `%` on integer to do a rotation. Yours can do a rotation, just don't use ints